# SQLAlchemy Select as Struct to resolve error "Subquery of type IN must have only one output column"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

How can I get the following [SQLAlchemy expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html) to work with bigquery (similarly to how it works with SQLite):

```
conn.execute(
        data.update().
             where(sqlalchemy.tuple_(data.c.person_id, data.c.person_name).
                   not_in(sqlalchemy.sql.select(people.c.id, people.c.name))).
             values(invalid=True))
```

This results in the error `Subquery of type IN must have only one output column` when run with BigQuery:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi.exceptions.DatabaseError) 400 Subquery of type IN must have only one output column at [1:98]

Location: US
Job ID: 4331d568-e06f-41fa-813b-9754574587d7

[SQL: UPDATE `data` SET `invalid`=%(invalid:BOOL)s WHERE ((`data`.`person_id`, `data`.`person_name`) NOT IN (SELECT `people`.`id`, `people`.`name` 
FROM `people`))]
[parameters: {'invalid': True}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

Using `SELECT AS STRUCT` in the subquery resolves this error -- how can I do this with SQLAlchemy (and why doesn't SQLAlchemy automatically do this)?  For example this works in BigQuery:

```
UPDATE `jdimatteo-v.scratch.data`
   SET `invalid`=True
 WHERE (person_id, person_name)
       NOT IN (SELECT AS STRUCT id, name
                 FROM `jdimatteo-v.scratch.people`
              )
```

---

Here is a full working example with SQLite, with the connection to BigQuery that results in the above error commented out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sqlalchemy  # pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.27

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite://')
# engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('bigquery://jdimatteo-v/scratch')  # pip install sqlalchemy-bigquery==1.4.3
metadata_obj = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
people = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'people', metadata_obj,
    sqlalchemy.Column('id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column('name', sqlalchemy.String),
)
data = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'data', metadata_obj,
    sqlalchemy.Column('person_id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column('person_name', sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column('data_foo', sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column('invalid', sqlalchemy.Boolean),
)
metadata_obj.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()

def create_records():
    conn.execute(people.delete().where(True == True))
    conn.execute(people.insert().values(id=1, name='Mary'))
    conn.execute(people.insert().values(id=2, name='James'))

    conn.execute(data.delete().where(True == True))
    conn.execute(data.insert().values(person_id=1, person_name='Mary', data_foo='good foo', invalid=None))
    conn.execute(data.insert().values(person_id=42, person_name='Bob', data_foo='chop suey', invalid=None))
    conn.execute(data.insert().values(person_id=1, person_name='James', data_foo='mixed up', invalid=None))

def dynamic_update():
    conn.execute(
            data.update().
                 where(sqlalchemy.tuple_(data.c.person_id, data.c.person_name).
                       not_in(sqlalchemy.sql.select(people.c.id, people.c.name))).
                 values(invalid=True))

def print_records(msg):
    print(f'{msg}:')
    print("  people:")
    for person in conn.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.select(people)):
        print('    ', person)
    print("  data:")
    for datum in conn.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.select(data)):
        print('    ', datum)
    print()

create_records()
print_records('initial values')
dynamic_update()
print_records('after update')
```

Comment: I tried the following and it didn't work:     conn.execute(
            data.update().
                 where(sqlalchemy_bigquery.STRUCT(data.c.person_id, data.c.person_name).
                       not_in(sqlalchemy.sql.select(sqlalchemy_bigquery.STRUCT(people.c.id, people.c.name)))).
                 values(invalid=True))